# Multiprocessing in python doesnt print any statements

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

Multithreading is printing the output but not multiprocessing. Searched stack overflow and answered questions didnt solve the problem.

Multiprocessing is not working.

```
from threading import Thread
import datetime
from multiprocessing import Process
import sys


import time

def func1():

    print('Working')
    time.sleep(5)
    global a
    a=10
    print(datetime.datetime.now())


def func2():
    print("Working")
    time.sleep(10)
    print(datetime.datetime.now())
    

p1 = Process(target=func1)
p1.start()
p2 = Process(target=func2)
p2.start()
p1.join()
p2.join()


print(a)
```

Even the print(a) is not printing the value. It says

```
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

Comment: Variables won't travel between multiprocessing processes (except in queues and such) – there's no way this could work as-is. What do you really want to do?

Comment: Edited the questions please check

Comment: As I said, variables won't travel between processes. If `func1` is being run in another Python process, it modifying a global `a` won't appear in the parent process. _What do you want to do with multiprocessing?_

Comment: I just checked with variables whether it is printing bcz to check it executes or not

Comment: Even the print inside the func1 and func2 is not displaying

Comment: When i try the same to print a using multithreading, its printing fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I commented, plain variables, be they global or not, won't magically travel between `multiprocessing` `Process`es. (Well, actually, that's a bit of a simplification and depends on the OS and multiprocessing spawner you're using, but I digress.)

The simplest communication channel is a `multiprocessing.Queue` (that actually "magically" works between processes).

As discussed in further comments,

- you can't use `multiprocessing` in an IDE that doesn't save your script before executing it, since it requires being able to spawn a copy of the script, and if there's no script on disk, there's nothing to spawn.
- on a similar note, you can't use `multiprocessing` very well from Jupyter notebooks, since they're not run as regular Python scripts, but via the Python kernel process Jupyter starts.

---

Here's a simple adaptation of your code to actually pass data between the processes.

Remember to guard your multiprocessing `main()` with `if __name__ == "__main__"`.

```
import datetime
import time
import multiprocessing


def func1(q: multiprocessing.Queue):
    print("func1 thinking...")
    time.sleep(2)
    q.put(("func1", 10))
    print("func1 quit at", datetime.datetime.now())


def func2(q: multiprocessing.Queue):
    for x in range(10):
        print("func2 working", x)
        q.put(("func2", x))
        time.sleep(0.3)


def main():
    queue = multiprocessing.Queue()
    p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=func1, args=(queue,))
    p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=func2, args=(queue,))
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
    p1.join()
    p2.join()
    print("Subprocesses ended, reading their results...")
    while not queue.empty():
        print(queue.get())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The output is:

```
func1 thinking...
func2 working 0
func2 working 1
func2 working 2
func2 working 3
func2 working 4
func2 working 5
func2 working 6
func1 quit at 2021-06-16 17:58:46.542275
func2 working 7
func2 working 8
func2 working 9
2021-06-16 17:58:47.577008
Subprocesses ended, reading their results...
('func2', 0)
('func2', 1)
('func2', 2)
('func2', 3)
('func2', 4)
('func2', 5)
('func2', 6)
('func1', 10)
('func2', 7)
('func2', 8)
('func2', 9)
```

Comment: I tried in spyder and got error, and tried in jupyter got only "Subprocesses ended, reading their results..." this as output

Comment: Try running it in your terminal/command prompt, not in an IDE, much less a notebook...

Comment: Just curious, why multithreading prints in ide not multiprocessing. I even tried sys.flush.

Comment: Have you saved the script somewhere instead of "just running it"? Multiprocessing will require the program to be available on the file system so it can spawn copies of it.

Comment: Once saved, im getting the output. In spyder im getting but not in notebook.. IDE working fine.

Comment: So the main issue im trying is, i used threads my system became slow. All functions are independant so tried multiprocess but it doesnt print anything inside the function and i thought of asking help here

Comment: So why didn't you ask that at first? Why did you ask why trivial, non-related multiprocessing code doesn't work? You should probably ask a new question with your actual threading code that makes your system slow, so we can help with that.

Comment: I was checking all with trial and error and didnt get answer for any so.. Could you please help